# Can you create AWS accounts from member accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations, aws-control-tower, aws-landing-zone

I am creating an AWS organization and some member accounts within their own OUs (organizational Unit). Is there a way to create new accounts in the OUs from the member accounts or is the only way to create new accounts from within the Management account?
For example: account a-acc is in OU a-ou and has a service catalog product to create new accounts in a-ou but not only there.  If this is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the only way to create new accounts in an AWS organization is via the Organizations API in the management account.

It appears what you want to do is provide [self-service tenant provisioning](https://cloudfoundation.meshcloud.io/maturity-model/tenant-management/tenant-provisioning.html) capabilities to your teams. There's a few options

- Use AWS Control Tower Account Factories expose them via AWS Marketplace to member accounts
- Use a custom AWS Marketplace service (e.g. the "old" Account Vending Machine solution)
- Build an in-house tenant provisioning process outside of AWS, e.g. with GitOps or an existing service management portal (ITSM)

With all of these solutions you need to implement a form of the "same OU" restriction you mention. For the AWS marketplace based solutions you can e.g. create a product wrapping the "generic" account factory and pre-populate the OU parameter for where the account is going to be placed. This means that you have to create and manage many different "wrapping" products.

From my experience with setting up resource hierarchies for enterprises on many different clouds its much better to stay flat and refrain from modeling your organizational structure (e.g. departments, teams, divisions) into the cloud resource hierarchy. Most IT systems outlive the organizational structure they were born from and re-organizing your cloud resource hierarchy is usually pretty painful. I'm just mentioning this here because your "same OU" restriction sounds like "I want to give this team their own OU and manage their own accounts".

If this accurately describes what you're trying to accomplish, here's some ideas for alternatives

- model organizational hierarchy like department etc. as tags on accounts instead of mapping to OUs
- leverage a cloud foundation platform that can enforce permission models (who can create a new account) and tagging (e.g. accounts requested by this team always get tagged with their team id)

Answer (score 0):

first of all
dont use aws organisations but use AWS Control Tower

secondly
either way cotrol tower or organisation
you can use aws service catalog to create new accounts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create AWS accounts from member accounts. To do this, you'll need to provide your Amazon account credentials and select the AWS account type ( Individual , Business , or Partnership ) that corresponds to your organizational structure. You'll then be prompted to enter your organization's primary contact information ( Corporate Email Address and Phone Number ). After you've completed these steps, you'll be able to create an AWS account and begin using AWS services.